# output/input mutiple files to desktop

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct

working on some code that will place (output/input) 5 different files onto my desktop.  Finally, got it down to one error message which is "error <23>: C2109: subscript an array or pointer type is required".  Its with myfile.open; I've tried -> operator.  Not exactly how to make this into an array, if that is what I'm suppose to do as I have tried making string into char and warnings occur.  Can anybody let me know how I can modify my code to correct this?  I'm relatively new to C++ and programming, only a few months.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct pizza{
string FILENAMES[9];
};

int main ()
{

int i;
char FILENAMES;

pizza greg = {"file1.doc", "file2.doc", "file3.doc", "file4.doc", "file5.doc"};

  cout << "Input is invalid.  Program will end. " << "\n" ;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
const char *path="/Desktop/Libraries/Documents" ;
    ofstream myfile(path);
    myfile.open (FILENAMES[i]) ;
    myfile << "How you like math?\n" ;
    myfile.close();
};

return 0;

}
```

---

Your suggestions helped a lot, and my program is now up and running.  (no pun intended, haha.)

Comment: Remove this line: `char FILENAMES;` Note that the program won't do what you want it to do, though: If you want to place the file into a specific directory, you need to construct a file name consisting of both the path and the file name. The constructor taking a file name does roughly the same as a default constructed file which is then `open()`ed.

Comment: You mean `greg[i]` perhaps?

Comment: Do as Dietmar says, and then use `greg.FILENAMES[i]`

Answer (score 2):

The loop should really look something like this:

```
const char *path="/Desktop/Libraries/Documents";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    std::string name(path + greg.FILENAMES[i]);
    std::ofstream myfile(name.c_str());
    if (myfile) {
        myfile << "How you like math?\n" ;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: failed to open '" << name << "' for writing\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char FILENAMES;
```

`FILENAMES` is not an array.  Even if it were, you would have to make it an array of strings or a two dimensional array of characters to do what you intend here.

What you probably intend to do is access the field inside `greg`.

```
myfile.open (greg.FILENAMES[i]);
```